# Count with join still not displaing correct count

Tags: codeigniter

What I am trying to do is create a list of how many replies this thread has. I can count the number of replys fine.

But what I would like to be able to do is count the user thread also.

This is what the out put looks like. It only counts it from my replys table cannot seem to get it to count from my join as well.

```
Username    Post
demo         2
admin        1
```

Should out put like

```
Username    Post
demo         3 <-- Because the user has asked the Question / "thread" and has replied twice
admin        1
```

> **Question** How to make sure it can count the user id from the join() thread table?

Model function

```
public function number_of_replies($user_id, $thread_id) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('reply');
    $this->db->join('thread', 'thread.user_id = reply.user_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('reply.user_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->num_rows();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Who_replied extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($thread_id = '') {
        $data['users'] = array();

        $data['thread_id'] = $thread_id;

        $results = $this->get_users_who_replied($thread_id);

        if (isset($results)) {

            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $data['users'][] = array(
                    'user_id' => $result['user_id'],
                    'username' => $result['username'],
                    'total' => $this->number_of_replies($result['user_id'], $thread_id),
                );
            }

        }

        $data['total_posts'] = '';

        return $this->load->view('default/template/forum/categories/who_replied_view', $data);

    }

    public function get_users_who_replied($thread_id) {
        $this->db->select('user.username, user.user_id, reply.thread_id');
        $this->db->distinct();
        $this->db->from('reply');
        $this->db->join('user', 'user.user_id = reply.user_id', 'left');
        $this->db->join('thread', 'thread.user_id = user.user_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('reply.thread_id', $thread_id);
        $this->db->order_by('thread.user_id', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            return $query->result_array();

        } 
    }

    public function number_of_replies($user_id, $thread_id) {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('reply');
        $this->db->join('thread', 'thread.user_id = reply.user_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('reply.user_id', $user_id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->num_rows();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Thread Table

[image]

Reply Table

[image]

Comment: could you provide sample data and table columns

Comment: @NewbeeDev add image of tables

Comment: Do group by thread_id

Comment: @GulmuhammadAkbari did not work

Answer (score 0):

Do sum 2 tables user_id columns

```
public function number_of_replies($user_id, $thread_id) {
    $this->db->select('t1.*, count(t2.user_id)+count(t1.user_id) AS total_posts');
    $this->db->from('reply AS t1');
    $this->db->join('thread AS t2', 't2.user_id = t1.user_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('t1.user_id', $user_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->num_rows();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Only returns 1 now

Comment: Maybe it would be 1 row or what?

Comment: I have had a bit of trouble using the joins but found another way around it have added my answer thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have got it working mostly now bit more testing to do

What I have had to do is create to functions for counting one for replies and one for threads

```
public function replies_by_users($user_id, $thread_id) {
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('thread_id', $thread_id);
    return $this->db->count_all_results('reply');
}

public function thread_by_user($user_id, $thread_id) {
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('thread_id', $thread_id);
    return $this->db->count_all_results('thread');
}
```

Then combine them and using plus `+` and then return it

```
public function total_replies_and_thread($user_id, $thread_id) {
    return $this->replies_by_users($user_id, $thread_id) + $this->thread_by_user($user_id, $thread_id);
}
```

And then use `the total_replies_and_thread($user_id, $thread_id)` in the array itself like

```
$results = $this->get_replies($thread_id);

    if ($results) {
        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['users'][] = array(
                'reply_id' => $result['reply_id'],
                'user_id' => $result['user_id'],
                'thread_id' => $result['thread_id'],
                'username' => $result['username'],
                'total' => $this->total_replies_and_thread($result['user_id'], $result['thread_id'])
            );
        }
    }
```

Out put now correct

[image]

Controller HMVC

```
<?php

class Who_replied extends MX_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index($user_id, $thread_id) {
        $data['users'] = array();

        $results = $this->get_replies($thread_id);

        if ($results) {
            foreach ($results as $result) {
                $data['users'][] = array(
                    'reply_id' => $result['reply_id'],
                    'user_id' => $result['user_id'],
                    'thread_id' => $result['thread_id'],
                    'username' => $result['username'],
                    'total' => $this->total_replies_and_thread($result['user_id'], $result['thread_id'])
                );
            }
        }

        $data['user_id'] = $user_id;

        return $this->load->view('default/template/forum/categories/who_replied_view', $data);

    }

    // Model code is just on here for testing purpose you should all ways create a model for it self. 

    public function get_replies($thread_id) {
        $this->db->select('reply.*, user.username');
        $this->db->from('reply');
        $this->db->join('user', 'user.user_id = reply.user_id');
        $this->db->where('thread_id', $thread_id);
        $this->db->group_by('user_id');
        $this->db->order_by('thread_id', 'desc');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->result_array();
        }
    }

    public function total_replies_and_thread($user_id, $thread_id) {
        return $this->replies_by_users($user_id, $thread_id) + $this->thread_by_user($user_id, $thread_id);
    }

    public function replies_by_users($user_id, $thread_id) {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->where('thread_id', $thread_id);
        return $this->db->count_all_results('reply');
    }

    public function thread_by_user($user_id, $thread_id) {
        $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
        $this->db->where('thread_id', $thread_id);
        return $this->db->count_all_results('thread');
    }
}
```